# Connectives in mediawiki's {{#if: ... }}

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I'm creating a template in mediawiki that would optionally include a piece of information only if that information is available. The information is obtained using an semantic mediawiki annotation in the article passed as template parameter. The problem is that combining multiple queries in one `{{#if: ...}}` with ANDs and ORs is quite cumbersome and error-prone. The way I'm doing it at the moment looks like

```
{{#ifexist: {{{1}}} | {{#if: {{#if: {{#show: {{{1}}} | ?prop1 }} |
  {{#if: {{#show: {{{1}}} | ?prop2 }} | {{#show {{{1}}} | ?prop3 }} }}
  {{#if: ... }} ... | ... }}
```

So the second and third `#if`s are basically encoding an AND while the second and fourth are enconding an OR, that is, it is something like `if ((prop1 in {{{1}}}) and (prop2 in {{{1}}}) and (prop3 in {{{1}}})) or ...`. The `#ifexist` is necessary because `#show` returns an error (that is not an empty string) when `{{{1}}}` doesn't exist as an article in the wiki. I have about 6 ORs and 18 ANDs, so you can imagine how long and difficult to read it becomes. I was wondering if there's a more direct way of expressing these connectives, specially AND that requires this ugly encoding with nested `#if`s.

If you're wondering where do I need such a long if, the actual template that I'm working on is here: https://psychonautwiki.org/wiki/Template:Summary

Comment: It sounds like you are streching SMW and MW a bit. Maybe there is a better way to organize your semantic data, to allow for easier querying? Otherwise, nested if's is the only way to make `or`'s in MW parser functions, afaik

Comment: Thanks for your reply leo. Do you have any concrete suggestions on how to organise the semantic data in a better way? What is the usual way in which parts are included in an article depending on whether the semantic data is available or not?

Comment: I agree it's stretching SMW a bit, but in my experience most non-trivial implementations end up doing that. More specifically, the stretching causes write-only SMW markup. :) One thing which I find helpful is to modularise a little by splitting some of the logic off by setting calculated properties in templates.

Answer (score 3):

MediaWiki templates are not a programming language; if that's a problem for you, you are probably doing it wrong. Try [an actual programming language](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) instead.

If hard-pressed, I would use [`{{#ifexpr}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23ifexpr):

```
{{#ifexpr:
  {{#ifexist: {{{1}}} | 1 | 0 }}
  and (
    {{#show: {{{1}}} | ?prop1 | 1 | 0 }}
    and {{#show: {{{1}}} | ?prop2 | 1 | 0 }}
    or
    {{#show: {{{1}}} | ?prop3 | 1 | 0 }}
    ...
  )
|...}}
```

If you need to choose between multiple outputs depending on the conditions, [`{{#switch}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions) and the old `switch(true)` trick can also be handy:

```
{{#switch:1
| {{#show: {{{1}}} | ?prop1 | 1 | 0 }} = option 1
| {{#show: {{{1}}} | ?prop2 | 1 | 0 }} = option 2
...
}}
```

Comment: The problem with using Scribunto/Lua is the (lack of) access to the semantic annotations.